# Is it safe to use ManualResetEvents in a Web API controller?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API that takes some incoming data. The controller puts the data in a queue to be processed by another thread, then will send an HTTP response after it has "detected" that the data has been processed. The design I'm thinking about is to use a ManualResetEvent. So the controller will put a reference to the event in a shared location then waitOne. When the other thread is done processing, it will put some status code in a shared location and set the ManualResetEvent.

Is this a reasonable approach? Is using ManualResetEvent on a Web API controller safe or will it degrade the performance of other incoming requests?

Comment: What would be the time needed to process an item?

Comment: I don't have any hard numbers on time needed. It should be less than a minute though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bad idea.  `WaitOne` will cause the current thread to block, which will eventually exhaust the threads in the thread pool.

You should either find some await-able implementation of a wait handle [like this one](https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/04/async-and-cancellation-support-for-wait-handles/), or use `TaskCompletionSource` to create a task you can await.

In either case, awaiting a task will release the thread back to the pool, so that it can process other requests while the data is still in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ManualResetEvent` is not a good idea. You just block a thread that is executing your action method and a new thread is executing your queued code.

The solution depends on what kind of processing your code is doing. If processing consists of one or more IO operations (DB operations, communication with other services, writing reading from file system) you should use async methods for those IO operations (most APIs offer ones) with `await` keyword and mark action method with `async` keyword.

On the other hand, if processing is just some CPU intensive calculations without any IO operations you can execute them synchronously with the risk that thread pool can be exhausted - if too many requests arrive, or create your own thread pool (aside of standard .NET thread pool) with limited number of threads where you queue your requests and execute CPU intensive operations. And at the end of every request processing you send an HTTP response. This solution prevents you from thread pool exhaustion, but it's not easy to implement.